# Display Emoji in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

from a web service I am bringing back emoji unicodes, e.g. U+1F601

How do you display them in a label? can I do it from the unicode value?

I am using unicodes from this list:

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: Fun fact: you can use the actual emojis in your code =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleColorEmoji" size:16.0];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0xe025];
```

You can see a full list of the encondings [here](https://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/adding-graphics-and-emoji-characters-to-apple-push-notifications/).

To convert the unicode you are getting to emoji, this does the trick:

```
let myStr = "1f601"
let str = String(Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(myStr, radix: 16)!)))
```

Comment: Thank you!, but where are you getting this value from 0xe025?

Comment: In my answer, I provided a link to a table with all the emojis =)

Comment: https://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/adding-graphics-and-emoji-characters-to-apple-push-notifications/

Comment: But if I do a find on the page I cannot see the value 0xe025 for example, I see values like \ue415

Comment: You can use some casting. I updated the answer with a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this is the bit that I was stuck on!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it

```
lblTest.text = String(format: "%C", 0xe04f)
```

Comment: Thank you, but where are you getting this value from?